# Editing column in csv file depending on its columns using unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have the following table is in csv format

> 07-04-2017   , YES
>       08-04-2017   ,YES
>       09-04-2017   , YES
>       10-04-2017   , YES
>       11-04-2017   , YES
>       07-04-2017   , YES

I want the first column to be compared with the current date of the system and if the date mentioned in the first column is in the past, then I want to change the 2nd column to "NO". The resultant table is:-

> 07-04-2017     ,NO
>   08-04-2017      ,NO
>   09-04-2017      ,YES
>   10-04-2017      ,YES
>   11-04-2017      ,YES
>   07-04-2017      ,NO

I tried awk statement but it is not comparing dates.Kindly share the command if you know how to go about this problem.

Comment: where's the comma in comma-separated-value format? and please add whatever awk command you tried

Comment: date=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y'); awk -F "," '{ if($2<date) {print "YES"} else {print "NO"}}'   But this is returning only "NO"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$awk -v date=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y') '{print ($1 < date?$1 FS "NO": $1 FS "YES")}' f
07-04-2017 NO
08-04-2017 NO
09-04-2017 YES
10-04-2017 YES
11-04-2017 YES
07-04-2017 NO
```

As per the comment - Todays's result for this command -

```
$awk -v date=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y') '{print ($1 < date?$1 FS "NO": $1 FS "YES")}' f
07-04-2017 NO
08-04-2017 NO
09-04-2017 NO
10-04-2017 YES
11-04-2017 YES
07-04-2017 NO
```

Comment: It is returning only "YES"

Comment: @BShiva - It is working fine, check my added result.

Comment: if you are only getting "YES" means $1 is always less than `07-04-2017` possibilities are high that date is wrong in your machine, paste the output of `date '+%d-%m-%Y'` command.

Comment: I had tried applying it in a table which had the date in the second column and had changed $1 to $2. But after separating the column the proper result came. Thank You.

Comment: Good to hear that it solved your Query :)
http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then there is no need to rely on any other utility. You can make use of POSIX shell *parameter expansion* and *substring removal* to parse the `year`, `month`, and `day` and put them together in a reformatted date string that can be used with `date -d "string"` to get the number of seconds since epoch (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`) and compare that against the current date/time to determine if the date read is *before* the current. You can then output `"NO"` if it is.

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=$' \t\n,' read -r fdate ans
do
    yr="${fdate##*-}"    ## parse year
    tmp="${fdate%-$yr}"  ## parse tmp="day-month"
    day="${tmp%-*}"      ## parse day
    mo="${tmp#*-}"       ## parse month
    rfdate="${yr}-${mo}-${day}"   ## create "year-mo-day" string

    ## compare date string with current day/time (seconds since epoch)
    if [ "$(date -d "$rfdate" +%s)" -lt "$(date +%s)" ]
    then
        echo "$fdate, NO"
    else
        echo "$fdate, $ans"
    fi
done < dat/dates
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/dates
07-04-2017 ,YES
08-04-2017 ,YES
09-04-2017 ,YES
10-04-2017 ,YES
11-04-2017 ,YES
07-04-2017 ,YES
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh datebeforetst.sh <dat/dates
07-04-2017, NO
08-04-2017, NO
09-04-2017, NO
10-04-2017, NO
11-04-2017, YES
07-04-2017, NO
```

You can adjust how the current day is compared if you need to consider 'today' not in the past, for example (now - 24 hours):

```
if [ "$(date -d "$rfdate" +%s)" -lt "$(($(date +%s)-86400))" ]
```

results in output of:

```
$ sh datebeforetst.sh <dat/dates
07-04-2017, NO
08-04-2017, NO
09-04-2017, NO
10-04-2017, YES
11-04-2017, YES
07-04-2017, NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `bash` version

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
while read L
do
    D=`echo $L | cut -f1 -d\ `
    if [ $D \< $DATE ]
    then
        echo "$D NO"
    else
        echo "$D YES"
    fi
done <./dates.txt
```

All in one line:

```
DATE=`date +%d-%m-%Y`; while read L; do D=`echo $L | cut -f1 -d\ `;[ $D \< $DATE ] && echo "$D NO" || echo "$D YES"; done <./dates.txt
```

Comment: The above code is returning only "YES" if I write it in one line.

In script it gives this error:: length.ksh[5]: [: <: unknown operator

Comment: It's probably because you are using ksh. Use bash instead. I'll write a ksh version later when I have time.